# Recursive method to read multiple csv files in Pandas

Tags: csv, pandas

I would like to map each file to its unique dataframe. Something like:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, ...)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, ...)
...
dfn = pd.read_csv(filen, ...)
```

for this I did the following:

```
files = glob.glob("*.csv")
for i in range(len(files)):
    df_i = pd.read_csv(files[i],...)
```

I get no error. However, I cannot access any of the dataframes. When I type df_1 I get "undefined". What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is assigning ds_i to a new DataFrame over and over again.

A possible solution would be to create a list of DataFrames:

```
for i in range(len(files)):
    dfList = list(pd.read_csv(files[i],...))
```

A better solution is to use a list comprehension:

```
dfList = [pd.read_csv(files[i]) for i in range(len(files))]
```

An even better solution is to drop the range:

```
dfList = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in files]
```

Comment: but I am indexing over i, does not make it unique? The above solution does not work. It creates a list of length 1.

Comment: `df_i` is just the text `df_i`. `df[i]` would be indexing over `i`, but you don't use indexes when assigning values in python: you can either `append()` to an existing list, or use the `list()` method.

Comment: updated the answer with a more pythonic answer using list comprehension.